# Locking in context of the isolation levels

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to find a simple list and general explanation of which locks can be used in a specific isolation level.

I mean I know in general:

1. Read committed isolation level

   - shared locks for reading (select)
   - exclusive lock for writing (insert, update, delete)
2. Read uncommitted:

   - no shared locks - means multiple processes can access one resource simultaneously
   - schema locks while changing the structure of the tables for example
3. Repeatable read:

   - shared locks for reading
4. Serializable:

   - intent locks (locking the resources in the hierarchy)
   - shared locks
   - key-range locks (reads or write to a row with a specific id key number)
5. Snapshot - no locking row versioning instead.

Could you help me to further grow my understanding?

Comment: I am voting for closing as this seems to be very difficult to be answer correctly. It will be best if you check this documentation - it's very detailed and it will give you the answers you are looking for - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you open the link you will see that it will take you 2 hours to read the information. If you have specific question or issue, I can answer it, but in the current way I need to post the content of the link itself in order to be able to cover all the details.

Comment: There are few other places where you can look for:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/04/28/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-2-locks-and-transaction-isolation-levels/
https://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/04/14/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-1-lock-types/
It is actually in the way that particular isolation level goes about shared locks

Comment: @gotqn i have read this article multiple times and it doesn't say specifically which lock are being place on the resources in a particular isolation level.